# pod install error - "Unable to find a specification for `React-RCTActionSheet` depended upon by `RNReanimated`"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-reanimated

I am building this app for Android and Apple TV .The app is working in android but in IOS it gives this strange error.

```
sanjaydas@Sanjays-Mac-mini ios % arch -x86_64 pod install 

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `ReactNativeTvDemoTests`: RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNPermissions, RNReanimated, RNScreens, react-native-config, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-video, and rn-fetch-blob
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `fmt` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/fmt.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-RCTActionSheet` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I am using

- M1 mac , macOs Big Sur 11.6
- dependencies

  ```
  {
   "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
   "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
   "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
   "react": "17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "17.0.2",
   "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@latest",
   "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
   "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
   "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
   "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.2",
   "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
   "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
   "react-native-web": "^0.17.7",}
  ```
- POD FILE

  ```
     require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
     require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
     ios/native_modules'

     platform :ios, '12.0' 

     target 'ReactNativeTvDemo' do
     target 'ReactNativeTvDemoTests' do
     inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
     config = use_native_modules!
     use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
     end

     # Enables Flipper.
     #
     # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
     # you should disable these next few lines.
     use_flipper!
     post_install do |installer|
     flipper_post_install(installer)
     end
     end

     target 'ReactNativeTvDemo-tvOS' do
     # Pods for ReactNativeTvDemo-tvOS

     target 'ReactNativeTvDemo-tvOSTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
     # Pods for testing
     end
     end
  ```
- Solutions used

  1. Updating pods. repo : **arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update**
  2. Reinstal cocoapods :

     - brew install cocoapods
     - brew link --override cocoapods
  3. React/Core to React-Core : **grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i '' 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'**
  4. Install ffi : **sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**

  I followed those solutions because they seems related somehow.None of the solutions worked so far.I have no idea how to solve this error now .Please help me .Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with RN 0.66.3

what worked for me:

- `rm podfile.lock`
- `pod cache clean --all`
- `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

Comment: I tried all of those .Finally created a new project and copied all files .It solved the problem.